# Trying to read audio file in python using IBM Speech to Text. code cannot detect file

Tags: python, speech-to-text

I am trying to learn IBM Speech2Text software. downloaded .mp3 file and converted to .wav, trying to open this file in python but getting an error2: No such file or directory

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgVKK.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and typing in your code and the error instead of linking to them?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest swapping the `\` characters with `/` in your url string.

You can use always:

```
'C:/mydir'
```

this works both in linux and windows. Other posibility is

```
'C:\\mydir'
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I realized that I was trying to load file in IBM Watson service which cannot read files from C drive for some reason. The same code worked when I ran it into Juypter Notebook in my computer.